# how toAccess FormGroup value in Html View

Tags: html, angular, angular-forms

Thank you in Advance.
I have question about how can i access FormGroup value.

I want check if value is null then button should be disabled.

In my App **form** is Coming From Child component as Input.

I have Created This [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-61aw4c?file=src/app/app.component.html) For checking my Code Structure.

Any help is Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly:
you should add Validation.required to each formControl that you generated

```
this.testArray.forEach((x) => {
  this.controlGroup[x.name] = new FormControl(null, Validators.required);
});
```

then in your template you should based the button on that form validation

```
<button [disabled]="firstFormGroup.invalid">button name</button>
```

Comment: yes you understood correct but validator will not work because i don't want to fill all the field in array. if only one has value the it should be enabled.

Comment: try this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-961em4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: i have Done similar solution but here problem is that it will only update 1st time if you remove the value from list then it will stay enabled (even when you add another condition for empty string it won't effect).